# some errors when i try to use scribe java library for yahoo authentication

Tags: oauth, yahoo

When I tried connecting to Yahoo via Oauth authentication using scribe java library, I get the error message "oauth_problem=consumer_key_rejected" I tried different sets of API keys but same error message is shown...How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Check with Yahoo for your application consumer key, otherwise you can ask to renew a new consumer key.